# UIImage UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

How can I pass an image that is in my `UITableViewCell` to my `TableDetailsView`.

I tried setting the data on Post, which is my type of data that fills the `UITableView cells`.

```
 [[cell avatar] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"butterfly.jpeg"]];
 [post setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"butterfly.jpeg"]]; <-- app crashes here.
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more information about what the Post object is, where and how it is created, and the error message you get when it crashes.

Comment: What is `post` variable in your code.

Comment: Post is my data object Post.h.  The butterfly image is hard coded as I was just trying to get it to work before I try pulling in images from the web.

Comment: What I need overall is to pull an image from the web avatar from Twitter and display in UITableViewCells then when the user clicks the cell I need to push the image to the cellDetail rather than make another uRL call to get the image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it seems that Question still is not complete....

But looking at two lines of code & you want to pass an image then you could do this thing in lots of ways.

so for testing purpose I will suggest ,just use a Global String i.e in Delegate.
like.Otherwise can you can use this link for Global Variable

[Pass a variable between lots of UIVIewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984702/pass-a-variable-between-lots-of-uiviewcontrollers/3985112#3985112)

DelegateClassObj.yourGlobalString = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@",@"butterfly.jpeg"];

from the class where you want to pass.

&

now if you want to use it:
Suppose post in your imageView then

[post setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:DelegateClassObj.yourGlobalString]];

Hope this will work....the easir way :)

Answer (score 0):

If Your motive is to Display same Image on detail view, then you can pass the name (or Id) of that image on cell tap. and load that image in your detail view through that.